# How to give my view page into html tag in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a laravel website, my route is like following:

```html
Route::get('/', function () {
 // Session::flush();
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('register','RegController');
Route::get('formdata', function () {
 // Session::flush();
    return view('formdata');
});
```

I have an html link like this:

```html
<a href="" id="logo"><img src="{{ asset('web\img\TEIA Logo.png') }}" alt="" width="300" height="135"></a>
```

What should I insert into href so I can get the corresponding view page?

Comment: What page you want to href

Comment: its welcome.blade.php

Comment: you can use "{{ url('/') }} like - <a href="{{ url('/') }}" id="logo">test</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
<a href="{!! url('/') !!}" id="logo"><img src="{{ asset('web\img\TEIA Logo.png') }}" alt="" width="300" height="135"></a>
```